# Vertical collapsed navbar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a responsive navbar with bootstrap which shows vertically the menu and hides it when you click on the button. The current code shows and horizontal navbar when I click on the button on a small screen and the button doesn't work when I want to close the navbar. I don't understand where's the problem :(

The CSS are bootstrap files and the only modification I made was on `id="barremenu"` :

```
#barremenu{
display:block;

}
```

.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container" id="barremenu">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="img-responsive pull-left" href="welcome.html"><img src="css/pictures/name.png" alt="Welcome" height="50px" style="margin-top:12px">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#" style="color:red">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 8</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You Will need to add your relevant css and javascript for anyone to be able to Help you. However, to create a "vertical" navbar you probably have to display your list items as a block element (`display:block;`)

Comment: Make sure that you have added the bootstrap and jquery libraray in your code and then it will work. Look at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5nhu9ogg/3/